# Is a Letter of Experience required to be stamped?

Tags: work-experience

I have got letter of experience from my previous employer on company's letter head, but it doesn't have a company stamp or seal upon it.
Would it be considered as a valid experience letter? Or is getting it stamped mandatory?

Comment: Does the letter have a signature?

Comment: ya it has signature of CEO on it

Comment: Can you please add a tag for whatever country this is in? Many places (the US, for example) don't even have this concept.

Comment: Why is this tagged relieving letter?

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill Well I was asked this in US so thats that ?

Comment: @guest because sometimes you get letter of experience along with relieving letter?

Comment: @Mk47: Then please write into the question what you want to know about relieving letter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be good and feel *authentic* if the letter is stamped.However, I don't think it is mandatory.

Plus, it varies depending on company / geography. In India, (where I work out of)as far as I know, it is required to have the experience letter printed out with a proper letterhead  bearing the employer's logo and seal, signed by an authorized HR Officer.

I checked this with a HR guy I know and he tells it is not obligatory for a company to stamp the letter(We are a MNC). I guess you are fine, provided the letter carries an authorized signature.

Comment: Plus, the company you are applying to will mostly verify on background checks. That will do.